# Copy files from Android app to an external thumb drive

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, usb-drive

I would like to transfer files generated by my app to a [Android phone-compatible USB drive](https://www.androidcentral.com/how-connect-usb-flash-storage-device-your-android-phone)?

Apparently, the drive gets mounted as a volume.  However, I don't know how to address the drive to copy files to it.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: what you have try??

Comment: Don't have any idea. I don't have any solid blogs to build this